# jQuery can't remove dynamically added row

Tags: jquery, append, row

Is there something stopping this working, I'm dynamically adding a row to a table, then if they click the new row (or any row in the table) it should disappear...but it isnt working?

```
$('.addtocart').click(function(){
                    var omPartNo = $(this).next().text();
                    var supPartNo = $(this).next().next().text();
                    var cat = $(this).next().next().next().text();
                    var desc = $(this).next().next().next().next().text();
                    var manuf = $(this).next().next().next().next().next().text();
                    var list = $(this).next().next().next().next().next().next().text();
                    var disc = $(this).next().next().next().next().next().next().next().text();
                    var priceEach = $(this).next().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().text();
                    $('#cart table').append('<tr class="tableRow"><td><a class="removeItem" href="#"><img src="/admin/images/delete.png"></img></a><td>' + omPartNo + '</td><td>' + supPartNo + '</td><td>' + cat + '</td><td>' + desc + '</td><td>' + manuf + '</td><td>' + list + '</td><td>' + disc + '</td><td>' + priceEach + '</td></tr>');
                });

                $('.tableRow').click(function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), like this:

```
$('.tableRow').live('click',function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Excellent! I'm trying to accept your answer but it says wait 8 mins!?

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the patience :)

Comment: $('.removeItem').live('click',function(){
     $(this,'.tableRow').remove();
});

Any idea how to fix the above, i want to click an image and for it to remove the row its in?? Do i need mulitiple selectors?

Comment: how about something like:
$('.removeItem').live('click',function(){ $(this).parent().remove(); });

Comment: $('.removeItem').live('click',function(){ $(this).closest('tr').remove(); }); now it removes the row it is in even if it is nested in another element :-)

Comment: Excellent DoXicK thats the one! Works perfectly :)